# lucene/Solr performance and hardware requirement

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am working on a project, where we are trying to introduce a searchframework for blogg data. We are struggling with estimating the performance of lucene / Solr over large data sets over 300 GB.

I am also uncertain if our performance requirements can be met using a single server setup, or if we need to go for a replicated, or distrbuted solution.

can anyone provide an estimation over the hardware and if using lucene is a feasible solution

Comment: A better metric is to find the size of actual indexable text content. Requirements for 300 GB of plain text are going to be vastly different from 300 GB of .doc files. Also, I suggest you to run tests on smaller data set (say 10% of data) to get some idea about performance and resource requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing definitive can be said without proper look at the data (or rather, at least simple benchmark). Indexing and search performance (which should be considered separately) can also vary greatly depending on your configuration.

However, [this article](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2010/09/lucenes-indexing-is-fast.html) should give you an overall impression of Lucene indexing speed -- it's possible to index 21GB of Wikipedia articles in about 13 minutes on a single modern machine.